# Add multiple values in case_when argument

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I am trying to create a new column/variable called "age_cat"
I decided to use the mutate function on dplyr. However, I want to combine two age categories and the last category doesn't appear when I print the results. How can I add 50-64 and 65+ age categories together using case_when? I tried adding "&" but only the 3 age categories appear. Also, these are character values. How can I change them to ordinal/factor variables? see my code below

```
df <- df %>% mutate( age_cat = case_when
(age== "16-17"~ "16-17",
age== "18-29" ~ "18-29", 
age== "30-45"~ "30-45",
age == "50-64" & age == "65+" ~ "50+"
))
```

Comment: Try with `|`instead of `&` or `age %in% c("50-64", "65+")`. `age` can't be equal to `"50-64"` and (&) to `"65+" `at the same time.